# How can I tell what hard drive size a used Xbox has?

Tags: xbox-360

I have bought a xbox 360 at auction, no box. How do I tell whether it is a 4gb or a 250 gb? There is nothing indicative on the casing that I can see. Is there a code or something?

Comment: The easiest way is to hook it up and check the system info from inside the console's dashboard software. Alternatively, you could try to remove the hard drive and see if there's any info on it.

Comment: @IvoCoumans You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to hook it up and check the system info from inside the console's dashboard software. Alternatively, you could try to remove the hard drive and see if there's any info on it.

Credit to @[Ivo Coumans](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/18669/ivo-coumans)

Added answer from comments as discussed in meta post - [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-comments-that-answer-a-question?cb=1).